# Simple question about Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Let $f (x)=e^{-2\pi x}\mathcal X_{(0,\infty)}(x)$, where $\mathcal X_\Omega (x)$ is the characteristic function of $\Omega$. What is the Fourier transform of $f $? I searched in my notes and in internet too, but I only found results about the Fourier transform of a periodic function; however $f $ is not periodic and it cannot be extended to a periodic function on $\mathbb R$. Can you give me some information? Thank you very much

Comment: Can you do the integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-2\pi ixt}e^{-2\pi x}\,dx$?

Comment: Compute an antiderivative to $x \mapsto e^{-2 \pi x(it+1) }$.

Comment: The result of that integral is $\frac 1 {2\pi (it+1)}$,  but I don't understand how is linked to my question

Comment: What is the definition of the Fourier transform of $f$ ??

Comment: A potential confusion you may be having is between "Fourier transform" and "Fourier series". Fourier series are expansions of _periodic_ functions (or distributions). Fourier transforms (and Fourier inversion) are fundamentally about functions (or tempered distributions) on the whole real line. Yes, there is some overlap, because integrable functions on an interval, extended by periodicity, are tempered distributions (though never $L^1$, so do not have a Fourier transform defined by the literal integral).